# How to convert a mutablelist to a collection to use addAll?

Tags: android, collections, type-conversion, mutablelist

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a service, and I'm working with a mutablelist to store the objects. The problem is that I need to add the retrived data to this mutablelist, but addAll says me that the type is mismatched.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is **nullability**. you are passing a nullable collection( your MutableList) to a not-nullable collection. one approach is to mark the MutableList as not-nullable by adding `!!` at the end of your nullable Mutablelist.
to give you some idea, check this snippet code:

```
    var collection:Collection<String> = emptyList()
    var myList:MutableList<String>? = mutableListOf()
    
    collection = myList!!
```

Comment: Turning off null-checking with `!!` is usually a bad idea though. Unless you can guarantee that list won't be null, this is just ignoring the danger the compiler's trying to protect you from. Like if this example's from Retrofit, `body()` is explicitly marked as `@Nullable` (https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#body--) - the warning's there because you need to handle that possibility to avoid crashes

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're doing

```
data.addAll(recursiveResponse.body()?.data)
```

You're having to null-check (with `?`) before accessing `data`, because `body()` **can return null**. If `body()` returns a value, the whole expression evaluates to `data`. If it returns null, the whole expression evaluates to *null* - and calling `addAll` with *null* is not allowed. So you can't pass in a nullable collection.

That means you need to null-check your results before you try to add them:

```
recursiveResponse.body()?.data?.let { results -> data.addAll(results) }
```

This null-checks everything down to `data`, and if nothing in the chain evaluates to null, then it calls the `let` block. Because the list being passed in has been null-checked, it definitely isn't null, so it's cast to the non-null type that `addAll` accepts. This is how you handle potentially null stuff safely - by ensuring that it isn't null before you try to use it.